# how to change the date format from "20/May/2020T16:35" to "20/5/2020T16:35" in Excel

Tags: excel

I have dates in the custom format as "20/May/2020T16:35" in excel, How I should change this to "20/5/2020T16:35"

Comment: `"dd/m/yyyyThh:mm"`?

Comment: Well that depends on whether the "date" is actually text that looks like a date or a true date and if you want a true date or text that looks like a date as the output.

Comment: This is to be done in the format of "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm", but this is not working

Comment: Have you checked they are actually date values rather than text? You can to that using the ISNUMBER function, it will return TRUE for a 'real' date value.

Comment: The format is in "Custom", As i checked with ISNUMBER, it gives me False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ISNUMBER returned FALSE it's not a date.

You can convert the value to a date with a formula like this,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "T", " ")+0
```

and then you can get the required format with this custom format.

```
dd/m/yyyyThh:mm
```